# How to get the count of lines in a output of a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

This is my code for getting a 3 digit combination.

```
a = input("Enter first number: ")
b = input("Enter second number: ")
c = input("Enter third number: ")
d = []

d.append(a)
d.append(b)
d.append(c)


for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        for k in range(0, 4):
            if(i !=j & j!=k & k!=i):
                
                 for count, i in enumerate(range(4),1):
                    print(i,j,k)
```

**Input:**

```
1,2,3
```

**and
Output:**

```
0 1 2
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
0 2 0
1 2 0
2 2 0
3 2 0 & more....
```

**My question is how can I get the count of how many combinations I have got?**

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Perhaps just count the number of times `print()` is called. Or put the numbers in a list and find the length of the list at the end. (btw what is the point of your first 7 lines?)

Comment: I don't see that `d` is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of your loop, create an integer variable and set it equal to 0. Where you print out the combinations (within the loop), add 1 to this integer variable. Finally at the end of your program outside the loop, print the value of the counter variable.

For example:

```
counter = 0

for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        for k in range(0, 4):
            if (i != j & j != k & k != i):

                for count, i in enumerate(range(4), 1):
                    print(i, j, k)
                    counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Comment: I have a question If I decide to change the range to (0, 9). should I change enumerate(range(4), 1) > enumerate(range(9), 1)?

Comment: @AbdulAhad most likely yes - but I do not have the full code.